# Div spacing issue

Tags: html, css

I would like the lines to be much closer to each other, but margin and height are not working

```
<h4>TITLE:</h4>
<div style="width: 290px; display: table-cell;">
    <h4>AAA</h4>
</div>
<div style="display: table-cell;">
    <h4>€ 123</h4>
</div>
<br>
<div style="width: 290px; display: table-cell;">
    <h4>BBB</h4>
</div>
<div style="display: table-cell;">
    <h4>€ 123</h4>
</div>
```

Result:
[image]

There is almost a full line size between AAA and BBB. That's the issue.

Comment: *"margin and height are not working"* - Not using CSS-Tables, no they wouldn't.

Comment: <div> is block level, removing <br> will meet your expectation

Comment: as a side note, if you are representing tabular data you should use a table and avoid non-semantic markup (e.g. `<h4>`)

Comment: Can you not remove the `<br>`? What is it's purpose?

Comment: I'd like to point out that using headers for display size is not really a good thing to do. You probably should consider using a normal html table and use css to style it.

Comment: The br separates both lines without it all text is in same line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use table

```
<table class="table table-striped" style="width:100%; table-layout:fixed">
  <thead class="table-head">
    <tr>
      <th text-align="center" colspan="2"><h4>TITLE:</h4></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr class="table-success" text-align="center"> 
        <td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle">AAA</td>
        <td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle">€ 123</td>
      </tr>
      <tr text-align="center"> 
        <td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle">BBB</td>
        <td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle">€ 123</td>
      </tr>            
  </tbody>
</table>
```